# How to make elementary OS use less battery?

Tags: release-freya, battery, laptop

I have a Dell Inspiron 15R 5520 laptop, with

- Intel Core i5 3210m
- AMD Radeon HD 7670 graphics
- SSD drive

I remember from the times I still dual booted Windows 7 that the battery life sometimes exceeded 3 hours. Under Freya, the battery lasts up to 1h 50m.

What could I do to improve my elementary OS battery life?

Comment: Thanks, didn't find that one while searching.

Comment: You're welcome Magnus. I hope it help you

Comment: When did you dual boot Windows 7. Batteries degrade over-time